# Frequency of each word in a set of strings

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column in a dataframe, where each row is a string. I would like to get the frequency of each word in this column.

I have tried:

```
prov <- df$column_x %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    tolower() %>%
    gsub("[,;?']", " ",.)

sort(table(prov), decreasing = TRUE)
```

in this way, I get the number of times each `string` is repeated.

How could I get the number of times each `word` is repeated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes do the job.

```
df <- data.frame(column_x = c("hello world", "hello morning hello", 
                              "bye bye world"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
require(dplyr)
df$column_x %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  tolower() %>%
  strsplit(split = " ") %>% # or strsplit(split = "\\W") 
  unlist() %>%
  table() %>%
  sort(decreasing = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a document-term matrix...

```
library(tm)

corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(df$x)) # convert column of strings into a corpus
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp)    # create document term matrix

> as.matrix(dtm)
    Terms
Docs hello world morning bye
   1     1     1       0   0
   2     2     0       1   0
   3     0     1       0   2
```

If you wish to join it to the original data frame, you can do so as well:

```
cbind(df, data.frame(as.matrix(dtm)))

                    x hello world morning bye
1         hello world     1     1       0   0
2 hello morning hello     2     0       1   0
3       bye bye world     0     1       0   2
```

Sample data used:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c("hello world", 
        "hello morning hello", 
        "bye bye world"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

> df
                    x
1         hello world
2 hello morning hello
3       bye bye world
```

Answer (score 1):

You can collapse your column to one string, then use regular expression `\\W` *not word* to split this string into words and count each word frequency with `table` function.

```
library(dplyr)
x <- c("First part of some text,", "another part of text,",NA , "last part of text.")
x <- x %>% na.omit() %>% tolower() 
xx <- paste(x, collapse = " ")
xxx <- unlist(strsplit(xx, "\\W"))
table(xxx)
xxx
        another   first    last      of    part    some    text 
      2       1       1       1       3       3       1       3
```